# T-SQL left join a table with UDF

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with Employee ID, and an UDF with ID as parameter. How can I join this table left join MyUDF on EmployeeNumber. Something like

```
Select T.*, U.* FROM MyTable T leftJoin MyUDF(T.id) U
On T.id = U.id
```

I tried CROSS APPLY but it returns too much row because of Crossing. I couldn't find left join equivalence of CROSS APPLY. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is `MyUDF` doing for a single `T.id` how many rows it will return. `Cross Apply` is the way to go

Comment: return a table with 1 row and several fileds

Comment: Then `cross apply` will not return too many rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select T.*, U.* 
FROM MyTable T 
           OUTER APPLY dbo.MyUDF(T.id) U
WHERE T.id = U.id
```

Comment: I had tried before with OUTER APPLY, without the whee clause, now i got exactly what i wanted. Thanks agian